# C++ Function returning an array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, lapack

I'm having a very (seemingly) odd problem when I try to create a function to return an array of objects:

So I've created a Matrix class to interface with existing LAPACK routines (i.e. explicitly storing my matrix column major, and having functions to interpret the stored values). I'd like to create a function that takes one of these objects and determines the eigensystem of the matrix (via DGEEV). I've attempted to create a function that returns a poiter (Matrix*)

```
Matrix * eigsys(const Matrix& m1) {
    <Memory allocation stuff that's irrelevant to the point>
    Matrix * eigs = new Matrix[4];
    Matrix WR(N,1), WI(N,1), VL(N,N), VR(N,N);
    <Do DGEEV, successful exit...>
    eigs[0] = WR;
    eigs[1] = WI;
    eigs[2] = VL;
    eigs[3] = VR;
}
```

If it's important, my equality overload is

```
54 Matrix &Matrix::operator=(const Matrix& rhs) {
55         if(this == &rhs) {
56                 return *this;
57         } else {
58                 if(n != rhs.n || m != rhs.m) {
59                         this->~Matrix();
60                         n = rhs.n;
61                         m = rhs.m;
62                         alloc();
63                 }
64                 for(int i = 0; i < n*m; i++) {
65                         mat[i] = rhs.mat[i];
66                 }
67                 return *this;
68         }
69 }
```

All alloc() does is allocated the 1D array for the Matrix

What's odd is that I can access the even indices with no problem, but the odd ones yield a Segmentation Fault. Any ideas?

Comment: Just to make sure; your eigsys() function is actually returning the Matrix object?  I don't see a 'return eigs'

Comment: `this->~Matrix();` Why are you calling the destructor explicitly?

Comment: 65                         mat[i] = rhs.mat[i];
Are you re-allocating the m*n for i ?

Comment: Yes, I am returning the object. The problem isn't in what I'm returning, local to the function, I can't access the odd indices. I can't worry about passing it back correctly once I get everything inside of the function to work (but I do have the return call, I just didn't include it).

Comment: I call the destructor to reallocate the memory if the dimensions are different than the original matrix

Comment: The dimension of mat is n*m. I'm storing a N by M matrix as a column order, one dimensional array (to pass into LAPACK), hence the dimensionality of n*m